# Human readable firease dynamic links (react native)

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking

My domain is
https://my-example.com

i want to make a dynamic link that opens the app on a user called fred so id like the link to look like this
https://my-example.com/fred

there are two options

buildLink and buildShort link, for both i pass the same thing
link: https://my-example.com/fred,
domainUriPrefix: https://my-example.com

neither gives me a url that looks nice to humans.

Is there a way that i can get a human readable link here?